# Check if a string contain multiple specific words

Tags: php

How to check, if a string contain multiple specific words?

I can check single words using following code:

```
$data = "text text text text text text text bad text text naughty";
if (strpos($data, 'bad') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

But, I want to add more words to check. Something like this:

```
$data = "text text text text text text text bad text text naughty";
if (strpos($data, 'bad || naughty') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

(if any of these words is found then it should return true)

But, above code does not work correctly. Any idea, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Should the function return true if **all** of the words are in string or if **one** of the words was found?

Comment: if one of the words was found then it should return `true`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For this, you will need [Regular Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) and the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function.

Something like:

```
if(preg_match('(bad|naughty)', $data) === 1) { }
```

**The reason your attempt didn't work**

Regular Expressions are parsed by the PHP regex engine. The problem with your syntax is that you used the `||` operator. This is not a regex operator, so it is counted as part of the string.

As correctly stated above, if it's counted as part of the string you're looking to match: `'bad || naughty'` as a string, rather than an expression!

Comment: Please note that `preg_match` returns the int value `1` if the pattern matches the given subject, but not `true`. Either replace `=== true` with `=== 1` or `!== 0`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#refsect1-function.preg-match-returnvalues

Comment: Thanks for the note. I did originally have it checking for truthy values instead of type checking, but it was recommended that I edit it to use the triple equals operator.

Comment: If performance is important, it's usually better to avoid using preg_match() for this kind of simple string search since it's fairly slow compared to other options like strpos(). Also it's probably worth pointing out that this matches  any substrings, not necessarily whole words ("badminton" would also return true).

Comment: @christopher what if bad has | in it, i.e ba|d

Comment: I didn't believe that `||` is counted as part of the string, so I tried the regex in an online tool. Actually, it seems that having two consecutive alternators in a regex causes an error :) Try it in https://regex101.com or elsewhere.

Comment: Please note that parentheses are being used as pattern delimiters in this code NOT as a capture group.  I discourage the use of parentheses as delimiters because it can trick a developer's eye while debugging.

Answer (score 36):

You can't do something like this:

```
if (strpos($data, 'bad || naughty') !== false) {
```

instead, you can use regex:

```
if(preg_match("/(bad|naughty|other)/i", $data)){
 //one of these string found
}
```

Comment: This was very nice @christopher example did not worked but yours worked: if(preg_match("/(bad|naughty|other)/i", $data)){
 //one of these string found
}

Comment: Agree with above comment. Thanks dude.

Comment: This one works because it has the required delimiters added. The optional "i" for case insensitive is a nice touch. The accepted answer is flawed.

Answer (score 14):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) does search the exact string you pass as second parameter. If you want to check for multiple words you have to resort to different tools

#### regular expressions

```
if(preg_match("/\b(bad|naughty)\b/", $data)){
    echo "Found";
}
```

([preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) return 1 if there is a match in the string, 0 otherwise).

#### multiple str_pos calls

```
if (strpos($data, 'bad')!==false or strpos($data, 'naughty')!== false) {
    echo "Found";
}
```

#### explode

```
if (count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $data),array('bad','naugthy')))) {
    echo "Found";
}
```

The preferred solution, to me, should be the first. It is clear, maybe not so efficient due to the regex use but it does not report false positives and, for example, it will not trigger the echo if the string contains the word *badmington*

The regular expression can become a burden to create if it a lot of words (nothing you cannot solve with a line of php though `$regex = '/\b('.join('|', $badWords).')\b/';`

The second one is straight forward but can't differentiate *bad* from *badmington*.

The third split the string in words if they are separated by a space, a tab char will ruins your results.

Comment: Just a small correction in str_pos: add `||` instead of `or` : 
```if (strpos($data, 'bad')!==false || strpos($data, 'naughty')!== false) {
    echo "Found";
}```

Comment: Just a small re-correction of the misleading correction above. Using `or` is perfectly fine as it is used in this answer.

Comment: For the record, the `count()` call is not necessary.  If `array_intersect()` is a non-empty array, then it will be evaluated as "truthy".

Answer (score 8):

`if(preg_match('[bad|naughty]', $data) === true) { }`

The above is not quite correct.

"preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred."

So it should be just:

```
if(preg_match('[bad|naughty]', $data)) { }
```

Comment: or `if(preg_match('[bad|naughty]', $data) == true){}` so it is not a strict comparison...

Comment: `== true` is unnecessary syntax.

Comment: I find using `[` and `]` as pattern delimiters to be unnecessarily confusing/misleading.  I see lot of new dev failing to understand that the square braces that are intended as a character class are actually pattern delimiters. I never use `[]` or `()` as pattern delimiters for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 4):

**substr_count()**

I want to add one more way doing it with `substr_count()` (above all other answers):

```
if (substr_count($data, 'bad') || substr_count($data, 'naughty')){
    echo "Found";
}
```

`substr_count()` is counting for how many times the string appears, so when it's 0 then you know that it was not found. 
I would say this way is more readable than using `str_pos()` (which was mentioned in one of the answers) :

```
if (strpos($data, 'bad')!==false || strpos($data, 'naughty')!== false) {
    echo "Found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to strpos each word. Now you are checking if there is a string that states

```
'bad || naughty'
```

which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using an array for the words to be tested and the [`array_reduce()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function:

```php
$words_in_data = array_reduce( array( 'bad', 'naughty' ), function ( $carry, $check ) use ( $data ) {
    return ! $carry ? false !== strpos( $data, $check ) : $carry;
} );
```

Then you can simply use:

```
if( $words_in_data ){
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: The disadvantage of using "functional programming" for this task is that you do not get to enjoy the benefits of an "early return" (short circuiting).  This effectively means that your iterating technique will continue iterating all values regardless of if it found a qualifying match.  In many cases, this is an unwanted behavior.  This is not an attack on this answer, it is just a word of caution to researchers.  A breakable `foreach()` is just as verbose, but will have better efficiency/directness.

Comment: No problem @mickmackusa. But actually, if any of the words have been found in the string, it won't check the rest of them. It will be almost like a short circuiting I believe

Comment: It is "somewhere in between" with respect to efficiency/directness. While it won't continue calling `strpos()` on each iteration, but it will unnecessarily iterate the entire input array.  In other words, it is "as good as it gets" for a non-short-circuiting technique.  Ultimately, I don't see any compelling reason to use this verbose technique with `use()` versus a simple `foreach()`.  If a dev wants something tidy that fits inside of `if (multiNeedleSearch($needles, $haystack)) {`, then just write a custom function containing the `foreach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that can perform this operation without using regular expressions which could be slower. Instead of passing a single string for the task, pass an array like

```
if (strposMultiple($data, ['bad', 'naughty']) !== false) {
    //...
}
```

Here is the function:

```
function strposMultiple($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0) {
    if(is_string($needle))
        return strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
    else {
        $min = false;
        foreach($needle as $n) {
            $pos = strpos($haystack, $n, $offset);

            if($min === false || $pos < $min) {
                $min = $pos;
            }
        }

        return $min;
    }
}
```