# Check if one of multiple words exists in the string?

Tags: php, strpos

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "it is a test";
```

I want to check it for these words: `it`, `test`. I want to it returns `true` if there is **at least** one of those words in the string.

Here is what I did: *(though it does not work)*

```
$keywords = array ('it', 'test');
if(strpos($str, $keywords) !== false){ echo 'true';}
else echo 'false';
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445798/php-check-if-string-contains-a-value-in-array

Comment: I don't suppose you've bothered looking at the rather obscurely-named [str_word_count()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) function.... `$matches = array_intersect($keywords, str_word_count($str, 1));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string contain multiple specific words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862361/check-if-a-string-contain-multiple-specific-words)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply checking using `preg_match()`, you can add many different words in the pattern, just use a separator `|` in between words.

The following will match partial words, so larger words like `pit`, `testify`, `itinerary` will be matched.  The pattern is also case-sensitive, so `It` and `Test` will not be matched.

```
$str = "it is a test";
if (preg_match("/it|test/", $str))
{
    echo "a word was matched";
}
```

Sorry, I didn't know that you were dealing with other languages, you can try this:

```
$str = "你好 abc efg";
if (preg_match("/\b(你好|test)\b/u", $str))
{
    echo "a word was matched";
}
```

I also need to mention that `\b` means word boundary, so it will only matches the exact words.

Comment: It does not work for Persian language. Anyway thanks, +1

Comment: @mickmackusa I was just a php hobbyist and honestly I haven't code for a very long time since then. Please feel free to edit my answer to give a better experience to any visitors :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to user the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function, this looks like:

```
$str = "it is a test"; // Remember your quotes!

$keywords = array ('it', 'test');

$str_array = explode(" ", $str);
$foundWords = [];
foreach ($keywords as $key)
{
    if (in_array($key, $str_array))
    {
        $foundWords[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach($foundWords as $word)
{
    print("Word '{$word}' was found in the string '{$str}'<br />");
}
```

*This is a function with printing also*

This gave me the result:

> Word 'it' was found in the string 'it is a test'
>   Word 'test' was found in the string 'it is a test'

I think the issue with your code is that it is trying to match an array as a whole to the string, try doing it inside a `foreach` loop.

Another way would be something such as:

```
$keywords = array ('it', 'test');
echo (strpos($srt, $keywords[0]) ? "true" : "false");
echo (strpos($srt, $keywords[1]) ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: I feel there is a short solution. but ok thanks, +1. Actually I want to it checks first word in the string if it was exist, then break and return `true`.

Comment: There are many other solutions, but this is one that gives a good overview of what is required, in a clear and readable way, hope it helps :)

Comment: @Sajad, I have added another method that is both shorter and faster than my previous, maybe this is more what you are looking for, hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, so sorry of i am wrong.
I think strpos doesnt work with arrays?

Try to do:

```
$array = ('it', 'test');
for($i=0;$i<$array.length;$i++){
```

`//here the strpos Method but with $array[$i]`
}

Comment: Your array decloration is wrong I'm afraid, it should be: `$array = [ 'it', 'test' ]`, arrays use square crackets, not round :)

Comment: Y sorry i am writing from my mobilephone ^^

Comment: round is fine, I use round one since bracket only available after php 5.4.0, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-95, but you need the word `array` before the round bracket.

Comment: @Andrew, thank you for that, something I had missed too :)

Comment: But in my opinion you still should use  the square brackets, cause a lot of server are still running PHP below 5.4, i spent 4 hours of work to find out that my server is running below 5.4 :(