# Why \b does not work correctly for some languages?

Tags: php, regex, word-boundary

Here is my code: *(It work correctly for English language)*

```
$str1 = "itt is a testt";
$str2 = "it is a testt";
$str3 = "itt is a test";
$str4 = "it is a test";

echo preg_match("[\b(?:it|test)\b]", $str1) ? 1 : 2; // output: 2 (do not match)
                                     $str2           // output: 1 (it matches)
                                     $str3           // output: 1 (it matches)
                                     $str4           // output: 1 (it matches)
```

---

But I don't know why, the above *REGEX* does not work correctly for Persian language: (it always returns `1`)

```
$str1 = "دیوار";
$str2 = "دیوارر";

echo preg_match("/[\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b]/u", $str1) ? 1 : 2; // output: 1
echo preg_match("/[\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b]/u", $str2) ? 1 : 2; // output: 1 (it should be 2)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You still need to add a proper description to your question.

Comment: @DanielCheung I need to check a string with some keywords. If at least one keyword exist in the string, then returns `1`, otherwise returns `2`.

Comment: maybe this answer can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33654119/5297359

Comment: @swidmann I have seen what you linked me before. It does not work correctly. I tested it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put your regex in a character class in `"/[\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b]/u"`, remove the `[]` from it:

```
"/\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b/u"
```

You could replace the `\b` by an alternative:

```
"/(?:^|\s)(?:دیوار|خوب)(?:\s|$)/u"
```

You could also change the `\s` with a negative character class that lists the arabic letters. I don't know them but it's like: `[^دیوارخوب]`...

Comment: Still does not work, your solution always returns `2`.

Comment: @Sajad: Really strange, here, it works, it gives `1` for `$str1` and `2` for `$str2`.

Comment: Oh really?! You've got different results?! yeah it's weird.

Comment: Just one thing, what is `?:` in this: `(?:دیوار|خوب)` ? and what happens if I remove it?

Comment: @Sajad: It's a  non-capture group, it's more efficient than a capture group if you don't need to capture the value.

Answer (score 1):

The `\b` inside a character class or inside a double quoted regex is a **backspace** character.

That is why the correct answer is: either use single-quoted regex declaration so as not to use double-escaping, or use double backslashes before `b` inside a double-quoted regex.

- `'/\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b/u'` or...
- `"/\\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\\b/u"`

See this [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uaued4):

```
echo preg_match('/\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b/u', $str1) ? 1 : 2; // output: 1
echo preg_match('/\b(?:دیوار|خوب)\b/u', $str2) ? 1 : 2; // output: 1 (it should be 2)
```

Comment: Excuse me ..., I don't know English very well, I want to know *'workaround'* is the same with *'solution'* ?

Comment: "Workaround" means a temporary solution that does not work as expected 100% times or works slower, because a real solution is impossible or too difficult/time-consuming to create. Try with words inside commas, Toto's solution won't work.