# PHP - Check if any of the words seperated by comma is contained in string

Tags: php

Here are my strings:

```
$CheckForWords = "infant, infants, kid, kids, boy, boys, girl, girls, child, childs,
                  children, childrens, junior, juniors, baby, babys, babies, bby43,
                  bbyb43, crib, inf51, grl53, Inf52, infb51, infg51, jnr, inf, youth,
                  jn52,jn54,infg52,ing52,infs,juniro,chd62,chd63,jrcl99";

$CheckText = "Green boy kid boots";
```

How can I check if any of the words separated by comma in `$CheckForWords` are contained in `$CheckText` and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`?

Comment: Create an array; Go through each element and use `strpos()`

Comment: A combination of `explode()` and `strpos()`?

Comment: Can you make a complete answer fist how to create the array and then how to make the checking ? Thanks

Comment: @TonyStark StackOverflow isn't a "code this for me" site. As it stands, your question shows very little effort or research. You should attempt to solve the problem, show us what you tried, and we can help with the areas you trip up on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string contain multiple specific words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862361/check-if-a-string-contain-multiple-specific-words)

Comment: replace the commas `, ` with `|` and use preg_match

Comment: What if "boo" was in `$CheckForWords`? Should that return `true`, or should it match only entire words?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I would assume only whole words as we have this bit `$CheckForWords = "infant, infants,...."` which would indicate such.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix That's certainly not an unreasonable assumption; I would make the same one. But the question would be better if that point was specified so people wouldn't have to assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it

```
$CheckForWords = preg_replace('/,\s*/','|', $CheckForWords);
if( preg_match( '/('.$CheckForWords.')/i', $CheckText, $match ) ){
    echo $match[1];
}
```

But only if `$CheckForWords` doesn't contain special characters. The benefit of a regular expression match is that the `/i` flag is case insensitive,  and `$match[1]` will be the word matched.

essentially you want a regx like this

```
'/(infant|infants|kid|kids)/i'
```

As seen here
 https://regex101.com/r/wU1iE4/1

Just as a side note you could add `[^\s]+` after a partial word to match everything but a space

Such as:

```
  $CheckForWords = "infant, infants,...";
```

To make it:

```
 $CheckForWords = "infant[^\s]+,";
```

Which would anything starting with `infant` and stopping on a space, however this will cause `$match` to contain said space.

But I don't know where you get the list from, personally I would just do the regx to begin with.

As seen here
https://regex101.com/r/wU1iE4/3

Comment: Depending on the use case - especially if one wants to match regular expressions as well - your solution is probably better. Do you by any chance have any knowledge about what the performance difference would be?

Comment: on further thought ... the good old buttbuttination attempt comes to mind. ;o) you would probably include `\b`s in your regex: `'/\b('.$CheckForWords.')\b/i'` for word boundaries, then you could skip the `[^\s]+`

Comment: @Jakumi - I imagine the performance is better then using arrays, via explode and intersect.  But might be worth testing out.  If the preg_replace could be removed it would be even better, then it's just preg_match.

Answer (score 3):

For a probably shorter solution (and one with more possibilities) you should consider [ArtisiticPhoenix's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642845/4275413)

```
$blacklist = preg_split('#,\s*#',$CheckForWords);
$text = explode(' ', strtolower($CheckText));
if($contained = array_intersect($blacklist, $text)) {
     print_r($contained);
}
```

The code first splits the blacklist on `,` with optional following spaces. You should probably find a better format (a strict one) for your blacklist.

Second line splits the input text on spaces, which is very lazy, but your example seems very simple, you could expand it to something more sophisticated for more complex input texts.

`array_intersect` checks for overlaps in those to sets (arrays in this case), which is: all the words in the input text that are also in the blacklist.

**edit:** added strtolower due to comment

Comment: this will fail on casing..  such as `Green boy kid boots` wont match `green`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix true, could lowercase everything. *shrug*